# Android Studio tools:context and imports and package necessary when using other people codes?

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

Hi I would like to know if I use(copy paste) the codes from someone application, do i need to include the package name at the very top ex: *package com.example.tutorial.login.sql;* ?  and is it necessary to have

> *tools:context=* and *import*

lib/file according to the package name? can i edit it to something else or just omit it?

[import example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7x6d.png)
[tools:context example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFqO9.png)

If i open the full application file with resources etc in android studio it won't have any errors but if i manually type the code creating classes etc there were many errors found. Thanks.

Comment: When you copy the code from another source, you need to change the package imports and every reference to their package structure according to the yours

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the package name to your own package name where you place the activity

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying the code then you don't need to import anything. But you should focus on the particular id's which are assigned to the view and widgets which are being used in your application. 
In tools context you need to mention your path to the class not to the one who you copied.